# Would silverlight or wcf be a good choice for what I want to acomplish

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I want to make a personal webpage that will stream HD movies/Music from a personal computer on my network, and allow the creation of playlists,favorites, a rating system, and potentially allow different profiles.

I have experience with creating asp websites, But no experience with Silverlight or wcf at all. What exactly would be the negatives and positives of choosing these types of projects. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has dropped support for Silverlight on the desktop so Silverlight is not a choice.

I don't know anything about wcf but you should be looking into HTML5 video and audio.

Comment: Thanks. Im starting to see people saying the same thing on other websites.